# J Oliver EventStore/CommonDomain SagaBase

Tags: cqrs, neventstore, commondomain

Why is SagaBase generic in Jonathan Oliver's CommonDomain library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has more to do with a poor design decision related to an assumed dependency on NServiceBus.  CommonDomain was actually a bunch of spike code that worked so well, that I started using it in production.  I was using NServiceBus which requires that all messages implement IMessage.  As a result, SagaBase requires some kind of type, e.g. IMessage.  In the coming weeks, I will be overhauling CommonDomain and perhaps inlining critical parts of it into the EventStore.  For now, you can just use AggregateBase if you'd like.

Comment: OK, thanks. By the way, CommonDomain+EventStore is a great combination. EventStore in particular is so good I'm replacing my own implementation with it.

Comment: That's great to know.  My hope is the EventStore becomes the de facto standard for event sourcing-based solution.  CommonDomain needs a bit more love still.